# Conflict Miss v/s Compulsory Miss

Tags: caching, memory-management, cpu-architecture

**Compulsory miss** occurs when the block is brought first time into the cache.

**Conflict miss** in the case of set associative or direct mapped block placement strategies, conflict misses occur when several blocks are mapped to the same set.

Consider a 2 - way set associative cache memory with 4 sets and total 8 cache blocks (0 - 7) .Main memory has 64 blocks (0 - 63). If LRU policy is used for replacement and cache is initially empty then total number of conflict cache misses for the following sequence of memory block references is :
      0  5  9  13  7  0  15  25

**My doubt is, will 13 and 25 cause only compulsory miss or compulsory & conflict miss both?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your definition of a "conflict miss" is a bit unhelpful.

A conflict miss occurs when a block is needed which existed in the cache before, but was evicted in favor of another block that had to be mapped to the same slot.

In your example, the accesses to 13 and 25 are unique, so they are necessarily first accesses. They cannot have been evicted before the first use, by definition. Hence, they're compulsory misses.

They may *cause* subsequent conflict misses (and capacity misses), of course.

Comment: what if there is a direct mapped cache which is completely filled, means all cache lines are filled with blocks, now there is a block required which existed in the cache before, but was evicted in favor of another block.
Will it be conflict & capacity both together as cache is already full hence capacity miss and there is a collision hence conflict miss?

Comment: No thats pure capaciteit.

Answer (score 0):

Memory block references 0,5,9,13,7,0,15,25
In 2 way set associative cache memory with 4 sets -
0,5,9,13,7 will be compulsory misses.
0 hit.
15,25 will be compulsory misses.
Any block accessed first time is always a compulsory miss.
You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40465392/6430403